# WPF (.Net Core) Record sound to file using OpenAL

Tags: wpf, asp.net-core, audio, opentk, openal

I am trying to record audio from a microphone within a WFP (.Net Core) application.

From what I have found online, it looks like the best candidate for recording audio in .Net Core is OpenAL. You can get OpenAL from the nuget package OpenTK.NetStandard.

I was able to use an [example](https://github.com/mono/opentk/tree/master/Source/Examples/OpenAL/1.1) to implement some code that makes the program play the audio as it is capturing it (a bit like an echo effect, which is why I believe the example is called Parrot).

What I am missing and cannot find any help online for, is how to save the audio to a file instead of just playing it back right away.

I think the part of the code that should save the audio to a file would go somewhere in here:

```
if (available_samples > 0)
{
    audio_capture.ReadSamples(buffer, available_samples);

    int buf = AL.GenBuffer();
    AL.BufferData(buf, 
        ALFormat.Mono16, 
        buffer, 
        available_samples * BlittableValueType.StrideOf(buffer), 
        audio_capture.SampleFrequency);
    AL.SourceQueueBuffer(src, buf);

    StatusBarService.WriteToStatusBar("Samples consumed: " + available_samples);

    if (AL.GetSourceState(src) != ALSourceState.Playing)
        AL.SourcePlay(src);
}
```

I think the data I need to save is in one of the following variables:

- buffer
- buf
- AL.GetSourceState(src)

I could only find [1 single example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52609092/4220401) code that saves to a file, but it is in C++, 8 years old, and it does a few things I wouldn't know how to port to C#:

- it creates a `WAVEHEADER sWaveHeader` object which holds info about the audio file
- it creates `vector<ALbyte> bufferVector` object which is saved to file (I don't have the `ALbyte` type in the OpenTK.NetStandard nuget
- writes to file using this method `fwrite( &bufferVector[0], sizeof( ALbyte ), 1, pFile );` (where pFile is a `FILE* pFile`)

Has anyone been able to save audio from a microphone to file .Net Core? I really cannot find an example!

Any help would be really appreciated! :)

Comment: check this out: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/audio-recorder-in-c-sharp1

Comment: @Rufw91 Thanks for the link. I thought you could not import those Windows internal dlls in Net Core! I ended up using SOX. however, i need to add the executable file and all its dependencies to my built code, so it’s not my fav option. Im going to move forward for a bit using SOX and then will look into building a set of interfaces for each OS following https://scientificprogrammer.net/2019/08/18/building-net-core-audio-application-part-1/